# Color Itemize inside tabular or minipage

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

What I'm trying to do is actually introducing a column in a beamer mode the as the second one next to it is in grey (transparent effect). But it will color only what is before the itemize. Suggestions?

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \usetheme{Berlin}
 \usecolortheme{beaver}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}

 \title{3D-Lithography}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \noindent\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
 Basic Problems of Single-Photon Polymerization:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item layer-by-layer type of manufacturing (limits possible geometries)
 \item suppression through undesired quenching of radicals
 \item diffraction limits
 \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
 \color{gr}
 Two-Photon Polymerization:
 \begin{itemize}
 \item kdkd
 \item dkdkd
 \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to say `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` and adding `\pause` before the second `minipage`?

Comment: @egreg EXactly, that was what I was trying to achieve, in my search I found an example by colouring it in gray. BUT nevertheless you got again a smarter decision! Thank you! So perhaps I should close the theme?

Answer (score 5):

A basic feature of `beamer` is the possibility to have *overlays*: a frame can be thought as consisting of many layers that can appear (or disappear).

The easiest way to produce overlays is to use the command `\pause`. By default the next layers are invisible, but one can set an option to make them “transparent”.

Here's your example using this idea.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  


\setbeamercovered{transparent} % <-- the next layers are grayed out

\title{3D-Lithography}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
Basic Problems of Single-Photon Polymerization:
\begin{itemize}
\item layer-by-layer type of manufacturing (limits possible geometries)
\item suppression through undesired quenching of radicals
\item diffraction limits
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\pause
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
Two-Photon Polymerization:
\begin{itemize}
\item kdkd
\item dkdkd
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]